# Зачем использовать рекурсии в C#?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Только подобрался к использованию рекурсий, и практически сразу возник сабжевый вопрос.

В видеокурсе и текстах, которые я успел изучить, плюсом использования рекурсии называется более сокращённая запись. При этом, например, факториал циклом описывается не сильно длиннее, и при этом запись гарантированно поймёт большая часть программистов, которые будут её читать. А чтобы понять рекурсию, надо сначала понять рекурсию.

С другой стороны, замеры времени исполнения показали, что разницы в расчёте факториала (небольшого, правда) нет.

А вот если описать сложение, скажем, коллекции целых чисел, то разница огромная, и не в пользу рекурсии.

Я допускаю, что описываю криво, но пока ничего лучше родить не смог.
Итак, есть класс SomeNums, реализующий IEnumerable(int); в нём есть список num, хранящий собственно множество.

Вот цикл:

```
public int CycSum()
    {
        int acc = 0;

        foreach (var num in nums)
            acc += num;

        return acc;
    }
```

Вот рекурсия:

```
public int RecSum (int step)
    {
        int acc = 0;

        if (step == 0)
            return nums[step];

        return acc += nums[step] + RecSum (step - 1);
    }
```

И вот я где-нибудь в Main делаю так:

```
var n = new SomeNums(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000));
```

А затем замеряю время и по сто раз произвожу сложение каждым из способов. Считаю среднее, и (вполне ожидаемо, в общем-то) получаю вывод:

- Среднее время для рекурсии: 0,034 468
- Среднее время для цикла: 0,006 387

И, конечно, если я попробую увеличить количество членов множества, то получу переполнение стека.

Я понимаю, что использовать рекурсию так, как это делаю я - некорректно. Но есть ли корректные способы? В общем, есть ли смысл использования рекурсии в C#?

И да, я в курсе, что есть LINQ с его Aggregate, но пост не об этом.

Comment: Есть структуры данных, с которыми удобнее работать с помощью циклов (например массивы), а с иными удобнее использовать рекурсию. Например, для обхода дерева с однородными узлами удобно написать функцию, которая принимает узел, выполняет над ним вычисления, а затем вызывает саму себя для каждого потомка.

Comment: Вообще, вопрос о целесообразности применения рекурсии достаточно спорный, и четкие рекомендации о том где и когда ее следует применять в общем случае сформулировать сложно. Просто попробуйте применять ее для решения разных задач на этапе обучения, чтобы "набить руку".  На практике, к решению о том что целесообразно использовать рекурсию может быть принято исходя из конкретных условий задачи.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать что-то циклами там, где рекурсия не оконечная. Ну, хотя бы самое простое - обойти дерево. Задача решаема, но уже даже в такой простой задаче можно замахаться писать без рекурсии. В то время как с ней будет легко и просто. Что до "понимать рекурсию"... Дело вкуса - мне обычно легче написать что-то с рекурсией, чем без нее - там, понятно, где она применима :)

Comment: Интересно, что о деревьях я вообще не задумывался, когда писал вопрос. Это, конечно, моя вина, но если бы примеры с деревом (или вообще любые примеры, где рекурсия ОЧЕВИДНО лучше цикла) были в учебных материалах, понять было бы значительно проще.

Comment: @Uranus, оформите свой комментарий в виде ответа, пожалуйста

Comment: @eastwing, оформил как ответ. спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть структуры данных, с которыми удобнее работать с помощью циклов (например массивы), а с иными удобнее использовать рекурсию. Например, для обхода дерева с однородными узлами удобно написать функцию, которая принимает узел, выполняет над ним вычисления, а затем вызывает саму себя для каждого потомка.

Кроме того, рекурсия нередко применяется в алгоритмах, там где результат вычисления зависит от результата той же функции вызванной с другими параметрами или там где сложно заранее задать число итераций. Например - [quicksort](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/29775/). Даже математические формулы можно выразить с помощью [рекуррентной формулы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0). Взять тот же факториал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это объясняет почему вычисление факториала так популярно в учебных материалах.

Кроме преимуществ, у рекурсии есть и известные недостатки. Одна из самых известных проблем упомянута в вопросе. При достижение слишком большой глубины рекурсии возникает переполнение стека, так как при вызове функции ее аргументы и адрес возврата помещаются в стек, размер которого конечен. Современные компиляторы умеют решать эту проблему, но для этого необходимо чтобы рекурсивная функция была реализована определенным образом. Так, если вызов самой себя является последней операцией функции, то компилятор сможет развернуть рекурсию в обычный цикл. Этот прием называется [хвостовая рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Вообще, вопрос о целесообразности применения рекурсии достаточно спорный, и четкие рекомендации о том где и когда ее следует применять в общем случае сформулировать сложно. Просто попробуйте применять ее для решения разных задач на этапе обучения, чтобы "набить руку". На практике, решение о том что целесообразно использовать рекурсию может быть принято исходя из конкретных условий задачи.

Comment: Кстати, я скопировал пример из википедии в VS, и всё равно получил переполнение стека. У меня что-то не включено, или в C# хвостовая рекурсия оформляется по-другому?

Comment: @eastwing в C# в отладочном режиме хвостовая рекурсия не оптимизируется.

Comment: Собственно, чтобы как следует проникнуться, достаточно было  самому реализовать дерево. Уже на этапе "проектирования" я начал что-то подозревать

Answer (score 2):

Вот наглядный пример из игрушки.

Есть поле с квадратами различного цвета и при наведении курсора выделяются все одноцветные квадраты, идущие подряд по вертикали и горизонтали.
А по клику они исчезают и структура поля меняется.

То есть здесь происходит рекурсивный опрос каждой клетки и поиск её одноцветного соседа, от которого после также происходит поиск и т.д.

Без рекурсии здесь было бы сложно обойтись.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без рекурсии тут обойтись очень просто, вопрос лишь в том какой алгоритм привычнее.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, Можете описать алгоритм без использования рекурсии?

Comment: Обход в ширину. Обход в глубину через отдельный стек. Система непересекающихся множеств. Битовые карты.